# ajax elements fail to render when selenium webdriver used

Tags: redirect, user-interface, selenium

I have a tree view and on click of tree nodes it expands and shows child nodes. These child nodes are rendered using ajax call. When Selenium webdriver instance loads it child elements fail to render even after 5-10 min. When i debugged i found ajax response received 302 Moved as header response. response contains "Reload the page to get source for: https://mydomaingoeshere.com/tools/targeting/geotargeting_ajax.php?action=get_region_children&id=23424748". I noticed this using firedug net tab. If i load the URL manually it retuns the child nodes. But for some reason it doesnt wor that way on selenium webdriver.Selenium doesnt reload the 302 URL. If i execute same steps manually everything works fine without any issue.  I am using firefox 24 browser and selenium 2.37 webdriver. Any pointers to solve the issue highly appreciated.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can 1. Have a look into 'http://solutions4selenium.blogspot.com/2013/09/expanding-tree-structure-using-selenium.html'.   2. Try using lower version of Firefox like FF 15.0